# Is this a good solution for this regex exercise?

Tags: javascript, regex, email

The problem is that I have to extract the email addresses from the provided text. This is my final code:

```
var a = "A towel, it says, is about the most massively useful thing an interstellar hitchhiker can have. Partly it has great practical value - you can wrap it around you dent@vogon.com for warmth as you bound across the cold moons of Jaglan Beta; you can lie on it on the brilliant marble-sanded beaches of Santraginus V, foo@bar.bar.com inhaling the heady sea vapours; you can sleep under it beneath the stars which shine so redly on the desert world of Kakrafoon; use it john.smith@blah.org to sail a mini raft down the slow heavy river Moth; wet it for use in hand-to- hand-combat; wrap it round your head to ward off glom@flop.net noxious fumes or to avoid the gaze of the Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal (a mindboggingly stupid animal, it assumes that if you can't see it, it can't see you - daft as a bush, but very ravenous); you can wave your towel in emergencies as a distress signal, and of course dry yourself off with it if it still seems to be clean enough.";
var re = /[a-z0-9-_\.]+@[a-z0-9-_]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-_]+)+/gi;
var output = a.match(re);
alert(output);
```

Through using this regular expression I eliminate email addresses like: hi@.email.com, hi@email.com., hi@e..mail.com and so on... Is there a better way of doing so?

Comment: is this homework?  also, I think google allows emails to be like `hi.@gmail.com` so you might want to be careful about the restriction

Comment: No, I'm actually in my freshman year of high school, so there's no-one else programming in my grade. It's from here: http://cheminfo.informatics.indiana.edu/~rguha/class/2007/i211/week13/hw13.html

Comment: @SB - What is the fixation with homework? The OP clearly says it's an "exercise", and makes a good attempt of solving the problem. What more can we ask for? `:)`

Comment: Is it .net ? 'cause the regex format could change depending of that.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this. Basic string operations would be MUCH faster..

Comment: @ykatchou Probably JavaScript.

Comment: @Pabuc, how would you do it using 'basic string opertaions'?

Comment: while a has '@', copy '_text@text.text_' into an array where '_' is blank, and check if your array contains any invalid emails with the help of a simpler regex.

Comment: What about text.text@text.text.text? @Pabuc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that :

```
[\w\.]+@[\w\.]+[\w\.]*\.\w{2,4}
```

- [\w\.]+ : First part at least one
  time with or without 'dot'
- @ : mandatory for email
- [\w\.]+ : first part of domain name (myhost)
- [\w\.]* : optional part of domain name (my.host)
- \. : mandatory 'dot'
- \w{2,4} : last part of host (.fr, .info, .tel)

Comment: This allows `...@.a...b...com` - the OP's regex is somewhat better, especially for the domain.